Golang cmd.Start() - cmd.Wait() does not give reason for error incase of failure. It only prints exit status
I need to print the reason for command failure but  I see only the exit status
cmd := command(comm, args...)
    err := cmd.Start()

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Mount: cmd start failed: <%s>\nargs: <%s>\nerror: <%v>", comm, args, err)
    }
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Mount: cmd wait failed: <%s>\nargs: <%s>\nerror: <%v>", comm, args, err)
    }

I tried adding buffer and redirecting output but did not work as expected.
What I tried with Stderr
     var stderr bytes.Buffer
     cmd.Stderr = &stderr


And I used stderr.String() to print error if any. This causes ContextDeadlineExceed for few commands

When you execute a command with cmd.Start and what for it to finish with cmd.Wait, the returned error only shows that the command failed. To get the why of the command failing, use cmd.CombinedOutput (doc here). You can add this to your code
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
   return fmt.Errorf("Mount: cmd execution failed: <%s>\nargs: <%s>\nerror: <%v>\noutput", comm, args, err, output)
}

DeadlineExceeded Error possible solution
cmd := command(comm, args...)
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Mount: cmd start failed: <%s>\nargs: <%s>\nerror: <%v>", comm, args, err)
}

done := make(chan error)
go fund() {
    done <- cmd.Wait()
}()

select {
case <-time.After(timeout): // this would be the time.Duration to determine when to kill the process
    cmd.Process.Kill()
    return fmt.Errorf("Mount: cmd execution timeout: <%s>\nargs: <%s>", comm, args)
}
case err := <-done:
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Mount: cmd wait failed: <%s>\nargs: <%s>\nerror: <%v>\nstderr: %s", comm, args, err, stderr.String())
    }
}
return nil


Thanks for the response. My original code uses CombinedOutput but for certain scenario(say rclone mounter) the command takes time for execution and throws DeadlineExceeded. So I modified code to use Start, Wait methods. which solves DeadlineExceeded issue.Now I see error is not returned in this new code.

Oh! I see. You can try reassigning the standard error of the command to capture any error message it produces. I'll update my answer to reflect this
